# How to deploy Google Glass Java starter on AWS ec2 instance with raw IP address only?

Tags: google-mirror-api, google-glass

Google Glass Java starter project - 
How to enable callback to an Amazon ec2 instance when OAuth does not allow Raw IP addresses ?

I have deployed the starter code to jetty running on an AWS ec2 instance.
Given only the ip address, I created a new client id in API console to use with this instance, and updated the OAuth properties file.

When I hit the index.jsp, I got the following error message,

```
Error: invalid_request
Invalid parameter value for redirect_uri: Raw IP addresses not allowed: http://xx.xxx.xx.xxx:8080/oauth2callback
```

I have even tried URL Shortening with gool.gl and bitly, which lead to the same error message.

So what's the best work-around?

Answer (score 1):

Like the error message says: Raw IPs are not allowed for OAuth 2.0 redirects.

To resolve this issue, specify a hostname. Amazon provides a really long hostname for every instance that is spun up. That will work fine. If you would like something prettier, you can point any domain or subdomain to that IP using a [DNS A record](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_DNS_record_types).

Comment: Worked as suggested, thanks. Used ec2-metadata command to find public-hostname: ec2-xxx-xxx-xx-xxx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com